# Combining singleton pattern and repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I implemented repository pattern to my software by the help of [this](http://bizvise.com/2012/11/28/how-to-create-a-simple-data-access-layer-unit-of-work-pattern-with-entity-framework/) article. One question boggles my mind. I think Database class should implement singleton pattern because user should not create more than one database context using `"var ourDatabase = new Database();"` statement. Am i right or is this situation not a criticial issue for usage of the implementation.

Comment: The link to the article is broken.

Comment: In my applications, I often use multiple different database contexts.

Comment: I fixed the link. Why Uwe?

Comment: What would go wrong when they create more than one instance of the Database class for one and the same database?

Comment: Singleton pattern for database assumes two things. You only need one database, and probably you need the same one the same way all the time. Are these assumptions always valid?

Comment: Yes, there is one db in my sw.

Comment: The problem with the singleton pattern (so much that it could almost be called an antipattern) is that it forces the "only one instance" assumption on the entire codebase. Too many unnecessary singletons and you're back in global variables land!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not have the database context as a singleton with Entity Framework.
For starters, each context instance tracks all changes made to it and "save changes" saves all the changes. So, if you have a web application and you made your context a singleton then all the users would be updating the same context and when one called "save changes" it would save changes for everyone. In a single-user Windows application this is less of an issue, unless you have different parts of the application working in parallel.

Also be mindful that the context caches data it has already loaded and tracks changes by default. In short, this can mean memory bloat and decreased performance as more and more objects are tracked - though in practice the impact of this varies.

From a performance point of view, Entity Framework implements connection pooling underneath the covers so don't worry about creating and disposing database context objects - it is very cheap.